# lapbox + cryptocode = Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: compilation-error, adjustbox

When I try to use `cryptocode` package inside a `lapbox` (from `adjustbox`), my code produces:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage [
  n,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
]{cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{game}{center,boxed}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

This is fine: \game[linenumbering]{A}{B}

This is fine:

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \lapbox[\textwidth]{0cm}{%
    ABC
  }%
\end{minipage}

This is not:
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \lapbox[\textwidth]{0cm}{%
    \game[linenumbering]{A}{B}%
  }%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the wanted effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage [
  n,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
]{cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{game}{center,boxed}{}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Goal: the left text should not be larger than this rule and go on the left instead:\\
        \rule{.2\linewidth}{1mm}\\
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth}
          \lapbox[\textwidth]{0cm}{%
            \mbox{I'd like to replace this with the game}
            %%% Uncomment to see the breakage
            %\game[linenumbering]{A}{B}%
          }%
        \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\linewidth}
          \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's the error you get if you put any display enviornment in a horizontal box (like `\mbox`) that only allows one line.

Comment: You mean lapbox accepts a single line? And can't I pretend somehow that \game is a single line, by wrapping it inside something? Or is there an equivalent to lapbox that works for display environnement?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want it to do you could nest a minipage inside it to get back to a vertical context but that's probably more or less same as removing it as you already have the outer minipage, or perhaps you just want to put the lapbox around the minipage instead of inside it. If you just post code that doesn't work without saying what you want it to do hard to suggest anything other than remove the code that makes the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh sure in this specific minimal example yes. I edited my post to reflect the effect I want to obtain.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your solution to wrap a minipage (actually a varwidth is better for me since it computes the width automatically) solves the issue,  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as explained in comments (thanks DavidCarlistle), it seems that wrapping my environment into a `minipage`, or better a `varwidth` (with an upper bound on the width) whose width will automatically adapt to the text gives the expected result (not sure why, but seems like I need to give a length larger than the box).

See also my recent question here [Automatically scaling pseudocodeblock to fit in the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675118/automatically-scaling-pseudocodeblock-to-fit-in-the-page/675124#675124)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage [
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
]{cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{game}{center,boxed}{}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

Hello
\begin{itemize}
  \item Goal: the left text should not be larger than this rule and go on the left instead:\\
        \rule{.2\linewidth}{1mm}\\
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth}
          \lapbox[\textwidth]{0cm}{%
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{ % Align better baseline. Better solution?
              \begin{varwidth}{10cm}%
                \begin{pcimage}
                  \game[linenumbering]{A}{BBBBBBBBBB}
                \end{pcimage}
              \end{varwidth}
            }
          }%
        \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\linewidth}
          \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```