# Automatically scaling pseudocodeblock to fit in the page

Tags: scaling, scalebox, cryptocode

I have an environment (`pseudocodeblock` from the [`cryptocode` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode)) that goes into the margin if the content is too large:

[image]

For now, I can manually resize it using `\scalebox` and `minipage`, but I need to manually tweak the settings as I don't know the width of the `pseudocodeblock` (and I have no idea how to compute it).

Is it possible to measure the width of this block and automatically scale it if it's too big to fit in the page?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage [
n,
lambda,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\noindent This block should be scaled to fit on page (ideally, if it's short enough, it is not scaled up, of its too big, it's scaled down), for now it is going in the margin:

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}

\pseudocodeblock{
  \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob} \\[][\hline]
  \\[-.5\baselineskip]
  \text{Run Alice will do some stuff that are hard to write shortly.} \< \sendmessage{<->}{} \< \text{Same for Bob}\\
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that the combination of `varwidth` (providing an upper bound on the maximum width) and `\maxsizebox` provide exactly what I want:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage [
n,
lambda,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}

\noindent Content already short enough is not changed:

\noindent\maxsizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
  \begin{varwidth}{10\linewidth}% Upper bound on the width of the text
    \pseudocodeblock{
      \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob} \\[][\hline]
      \\[-.5\baselineskip]
      \text{Run Alice.} \< \sendmessage{<->}{} \< \text{Run Bob}\\
    }
  \end{varwidth}
}

\noindent Too large content is shrinked


\noindent\maxsizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
  \begin{varwidth}{10\linewidth}% Upper bound on the width of the text
    \pseudocodeblock{
      \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob} \\[][\hline]
      \\[-.5\baselineskip]
      \text{Run Alice will do some stuff that are hard to write shortly.} \< \sendmessage{<->}{} \< \text{Same for Bob}\\
    }
  \end{varwidth}
}

\end{document}
```

You can also create an environment to do that automatically with:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{autoFit}{O{\linewidth}}{\noindent\maxsizebox{\linewidth}{!}\bgroup%
    \begin{varwidth}{10\linewidth}% Upper bound on the width of the text
    }{\end{varwidth}\egroup}
```